# using SUM with multiple tables gives unexpected results

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm not real experienced with database queries, and can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a simple database with 2 tables, log and block.

```
Log:
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| srcip    | varchar(25)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| dstip    | varchar(25)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| cnt      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Block: 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ip    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| shun  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       | 
| count | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

My problem is this.  When running the following query, the sum(cnt) gives unexpected results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT srcip, SUM(cnt) as hitcnt, COUNT(DISTINCT dstip) as dstcnt
FROM  block,log
WHERE (dstip LIKE '10.10.10.%'
AND block.ip != srcip
AND srcip NOT LIKE  '$restricted'
AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $start_units $units)
AND time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $end_units $units))
GROUP BY srcip
ORDER BY hitcnt, INET_ATON(srcip) asc;"
```

If I run the same query and remove the log table and the statement that refers to it, the sum for each IP address is correct.  The reason for using both tables is that I only want to show IP addresses that are not being blocked. Blocked IP info is contained in the block table.  I've already figured out how to show only the blocked IP addresses using both tables, but showing the inverse seems to be eluding me.

I have a few more queries to build, I think if I can get this one working the rest should fall  in to place.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You.

UPDATE:
This works except the SUM is still off.  Everything else looks good.  Note I removed a line or two to keep it simple for testing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT srcip, SUM(cnt) as hitcnt, COUNT(DISTINCT dstip) as dstcnt
FROM  log a JOIN block b
ON a.srcip != b.ip
WHERE (dstip LIKE '10.10.10.%'
AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 hour)
AND time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 0 hour)
AND srcip != ip)
GROUP BY srcip
HAVING hitcnt >= '2' AND dstcnt >= '2'
ORDER BY hitcnt, INET_ATON(srcip) ASC;
```

I GOT IT!!  I knew y'all would lead me in the right direction. Thank you all for your help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT srcip, SUM(cnt) as hitcnt, COUNT(DISTINCT dstip) as dstcnt
FROM  log a LEFT JOIN block b
ON srcip = ip
WHERE (dstip LIKE '10.10.10.%' 
AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $start_units $units)
AND time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $end_units $units))
GROUP BY srcip
HAVING hitcnt >= '2' AND dstcnt >= '2'
ORDER BY hitcnt, INET_ATON(srcip) ASC;
```

Comment: You're join is a cross join all rows in block * all rows in log.  How do these actually relate to eachother?   a block IP relates to a srcIP or a block IP relates to a dstip? or both or what?  instead of it being this 1 row in block ties to these 5 in log.  The 1 row is tied to every row in log.  This artificually inflates the counts and sum of counts.

Comment: the log table holds a log of all activity.  The block table contains srcip addresses that have been blocked.  Once they've been added to the block table they stay there.  The shun column show whether or not they are currently blocked.  The count column is the number of times they've been blocked.  The idea is to report only srcip's that are not currently blocked.  There are two methods of showing blocked IPs.  1, show all blocked with all time counts, 2 show reports of blocked with all other flags in tact.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As xQbert mentioned, you do a cross join by `FROM block, log`, which gives you every row from `log` as often as you have rows in `block`. Then you filter some of them out, but you still have mor rows than before.

A solution would be a subselect.

```
SELECT DISTINCT log.srcip, 
    (SELECT SUM(cnt) FROM log WHERE log.srcip = srcip) as hitcnt, COUNT(DISTINCT dstip) as dstcnt
FROM  block,log
WHERE (dstip LIKE '10.10.10.%'
AND block.ip != srcip
AND srcip NOT LIKE  '$restricted'
AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $start_units $units)
AND time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $end_units $units))
GROUP BY srcip
ORDER BY hitcnt, INET_ATON(srcip) ASC
```

Or you can use the subselect to create a thrid table to join with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT log.srcip, hitcnt, COUNT(DISTINCT dstip) as dstcnt
FROM  block,log,(SELECT srcip, SUM(cnt) as hitcnt FROM log GROUP BY srcip) t
WHERE (dstip LIKE '10.10.10.%'
AND block.ip != log.srcip
AND log.srcip = t.srcip
AND log.srcip NOT LIKE  '$restricted'
AND time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $start_units $units)
AND time <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $end_units $units))
GROUP BY log.srcip
ORDER BY hitcnt, INET_ATON(srcip) ASC
```

Comment: I can't get either of the queries to work... yet! ;)  The first one show the same count for all.  The second throws an error.  That's okay though, it's a start and I appreciate the input.  I'll tinker around with them today.  Thank You. MPH

Comment: Sry, i had not time to test it. The same *count*? you mean the same `COUNT(DISTINCT dstip)`? this should then also be the case with your first query. The error in the secound one could that `srcip`  in line 1,4,5 and 9  is not uniqiem so you have to use `log.srcip` instead

Comment: I got it, see my edit at the top.  I could not have done it without your help.  As I said, I just needed a point in the right direction. Thanks!